# jquery animation fixed position

Tags: jquery, animation

Bellow is my code for a contact form which expands as a user clicks it

```
$(document).bind('click',
            function() {
$('div#contactable_inner').animate({"marginLeft": "-=387px"}, "slow")
            });
```

For each click, the element moves to -387px. I want it to move -387px only for the 1st click. For all the next clicks, it should not animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).one('click',
            function() {
$('div#contactable_inner').animate({"marginLeft": "-=387px"}, "slow")
            });
```

`.one()` which fires for only one time.

Read about [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one)

Comment: Thanks thecodeparadox. It solved my issue in seconds. That was helpful.